# What is the actual height of a container without scrollbars?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, mxml

Probably a silly question but, what is the actual height of a container in Flex without scrollbars?  Height and measuredheight seem to tell me what the visual height of a container is, but I want to know that number plus any height that is being 'hidden" below a scrollbar.

Thanks.

Comment: it depends on the container.  Can you give an example?

Comment: I'm curious about Hbox and Vbox in general, but I'm also wondering about SWFLoader. Beyond the scope of this question, I'm having a hard time loading a swfloader into a popup without scrollbars, and the height of the content in the SWFloader always seems to come up shorter than it actually is.

Comment: Generally 20 pixels. Sounds like your swfloader is being constrained by an outside container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the height with this:

```
box.mx_internal::getScrollableRect().height;
```

Answer (score 0):

HBox and VBox *always* resizes to it's children if I remember correctly.  So the height/width property will always be that of the content within it.

As for SWFLoader, it acts more like a Canvas.  If you want to get the width/height of the content, just use the contentHeight/contentWidth property.  The height/width of SWFLoader should be the size of the "Canvas" and not it's children.

I believe for the scrollbar itself, only certain components do that (like canvas), and I believe the algorithm to add the scrollbar is along the lines of `if contentHeight > height => add vertical scrollbar`. The HBox and VBox shouldn't ever get a scrollbar, unless you specify the 'clipContent' property to true.  I personally would steer away from using that and instead just wrap it in a Canvas.

Comment: HBox and VBox always resize to it's children if you don't specify a height.  If you do specify a "height", and the size of the children exceed that height, it will create a scrollbar.  I want to know the height that was specified plus the height of the content that wouldn't fit (beneath the scrollbar).  Basically the height of all the children.

Comment: I tried using contentHeight and swfloader.content.height for the SWFloader, but it always returns a number smaller than what I know it really is. The swfLoader is inside a VBox with height=100%. Interestingly enough, it seems that the scrollbars are inside the actual swf application I've embedded via swfLoader.

Comment: Really I just want to know the answer to the original question- the issue with the swfloader is a little more complex, and can't be reproduced when simplifying the code.  

Is there a property that has the number of the entire height of a vbox/hbox, including what is below the scrollbar?  Or can I measure the area below the scrollbar somehow on creation complete?